# Internal server error running Django on Heroku accessing from browser

Tags: django, heroku

I think this is a simple fix, but I've deployed quite a few Django apps to Heroku and I still can't figure out what's going on.

Accessing https://dundjeon-finder.herokuapp.com/ gives me a 500 error when using the browser/curl, but if I shell into the app using `heroku run ./manage.py shell` I can render the views no problem. My logs aren't telling me anything (just that the response is 500) despite DEBUG being set to True, and Sentry isn't receiving an error (it has previously when the database env variable was set badly), so I'm assuming it's something to do with the way the request works.

The [repo is public](https://github.com/tomhamiltonstubber/dundjeon-finder/), any help would be much appreciated! The settings file is [here](https://github.com/tomhamiltonstubber/dundjeon-finder/blob/master/DungeonFinder/settings.py).

Comment: you can set DEBUG=True in your settings, after you check the error message, you can fix the error and set DEBUG=False again.

Comment: DEBUG is set to true

Answer (score 0):

Well it was because of using `asgi` instead of `wsgi`. I'm not sure why that caused the errors, but will do some more searching.